# Javascript: document.getElementById("el").style.display returns empty string but is not?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some basic javascript code which just checks if an element is block or none (display: block or display: none). It's my very first time falling on that issue as it works perfectly on one of my other websites. Here is my code:

```
function loading(){
    var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
    if (loader.style.display == "block"){
        var child = document.getElementById("loader-ul").childNodes;
        alert(child);
    }
    else{
        alert(loader.style.display);
    }
}
```

css (which is necessary):

```
#loader{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

html (which is necessary):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <header>
        <title>myweb</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </header>
    <body onclick="loading()">
        <div id="loader">
            <div class="center">
                <ul id="loader-ul">
                    <li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**FACTS**

- I have experience with javascript (as this code is just to check if
  everything is working
- I spent hours on looking on that simple bug and I have no idea how
  and why
- Never had such a bug like this (if I had, it was because I didn't
  have the attribute in CSS or I haven't linked JavaScript to HTML
  correctly).

Comment: @Oriol The question that you marked as duplicate with the question you requested are not the same...

Comment: You want to get `display` and that question wants to get `top`. I guess you can deduce from there, can't you?

Comment: @Oriol I tried that question and it didn't work.

Comment: Gaby's answer tells you to use `getComputedStyle`, and you say it works. Top answer in that other questions tells you to use `getComputedStyle`, and you say it doesn't work. I can't comprehend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) will return the inline `style` attribute values

Use the [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to see the rendered style.

```js
function loading(){
    var loader = document.getElementById("loader"),
        display = window.getComputedStyle(loader).display;
    if (display == "block"){
        var child = document.getElementById("loader-ul").childNodes;
        alert(child);
    }
    else{
        alert(display);
    }
}
```

```css
#loader{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <header>
        <title>myweb</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </header>
    <body onclick="loading()">
        <div id="loader">
            <div class="center">
                <ul id="loader-ul">
                    <li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    </li><li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! IT works! But why my code didn't work? (I am asking because it worked on my other website design)

Comment: @GeorGios are you sure that on your other site you were not setting/changing the display property from JS (*or that it was not hardcoded in the html*)? Because when you change the style through JS it is applied on the element through the `style` attribute. If you have a link to the other site i could have a look and tell you why it worked there.

Answer (score 2):

document.style doesn't return style cascaded from stylesheet, only the ones set by JavaScript or within the element using style attribute...
Use getComputedStyle instead

```
var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
var loadDisplay = window.getComputedStyle(loader, null).getPropertyValue("display");
```